# fwprintf: only the first character from a wide char array argument gets copied to output

Tags: c, io, string-formatting, wchar

I'm trying to write a message containing "alpha = abcd" to a text file using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int
main()
{
        const wchar_t *a = L"abcd", *msg = L"alpha = %s\n";
        FILE          *f = fopen("./deleteme", "a");

        fwprintf(f, msg, a);
        fclose(f);
}
```

However, after compiling and executing the program I get this output instead:

> alpha = a

Why only the first character from the const `a` gets copied to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
L"alpha = %s\n";
```

to:

```
L"alpha = %S\n";
```

The argument (`a = L"abcd"`) you are trying to print is a **wide** string, and therefore you need **`%S`** (uppercase) instead of **`%s`** (lowercase). Using incorrect format specifiers for `printf`-like functions is undefined behaviour.

Read the [documentation for printf format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions).

Answer (score 1):

With a C99 compliant compiler , use `"%ls"`.

> If an `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of `wchar_t` type. C11dr §7.29.2.1 10.

```
// const wchar_t *msg = L"alpha = %s\n";
const wchar_t *msg = L"alpha = %ls\n";
```

Comment: @Kais Does this work for your compiler?  If not, what compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Yes. BTW, I'm using gcc 6.3.0 under linux.

Comment: @Kais I use `6.4.0`, yet the issue may be more of the library version: [Ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120380/what-c-library-version-does-my-system-use) - mine is 2.9.0

Comment: It might be the case .. mine is 2.24.